# HTML5 Offline feature doesn't work on Heroku server though It runs perfectly on dev machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, heroku, asset-pipeline, offline-caching

Here is the related source code:

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure :cache_interval => 120 do      
 Rails.application.assets.each_logical_path.select{|e| not e.include? ".pdf"}.
    each {|e| cache "assets/" + e}
 network "/"  
end   
match "/application.manifest" => offline
```

Generated [manifest](https://muster-apotheke.splettville.com/application.manifest) seems fine, assets too, but it will stop downloading/caching assets in a random step with this message on Chrome: `https://muster-apotheke.splettville.com/application.manifest`

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the asset_path helper method, I can refer to production assets in cache manifest:

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    offline = Rack::Offline.configure :cache_interval => 120 do      
      cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
      cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
      network "/"  
    end
    match "/application.manifest" => offline  
  else
    offline = Rack::Offline.configure :cache_interval => 120 do      
      Rails.application.assets.each_logical_path.select{|e| not e.include? ".pdf"}.each {|e| cache "assets/" + e}
      network "/"  
    end    
    match "/application.manifest" => offline  
  end
```